# How to create linkedin login in angular 9?

Tags: authentication, linkedin-api, angular9

I am try login in angular 9 using linked in but can't find any possible way do it.
I have googled this  but I can't find any social login library for angular 9 which work for linkedin.
All library using angular 6 or less version. 
I have tried many social login library angular 9.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
    function onLinkedInLoad() {
        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
    }

    // Use the API call wrapper to request the member's profile data
    function getProfileData() {
        IN.API.Profile("me").fields("id", "first-name", "last-name", "headline", "location", "picture-url", "public-profile-url", "email-address").result(displayProfileData).error(onError);
    }

    // Handle the successful return from the API call
    function displayProfileData(data) {
        var user = data.values[0];
        document.getElementById("picture").innerHTML = '<img src="'+user.pictureUrl+'" />';
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = user.firstName+' '+user.lastName;
        document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = user.headline;
        document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = user.emailAddress;
        document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = user.location.name;
        document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = '<a href="'+user.publicProfileUrl+'" target="_blank">Visit profile</a>';
        document.getElementById('profileData').style.display = 'block';
    }

    // Handle an error response from the API call
    function onError(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    // Destroy the session of linkedin
    function logout(){
        IN.User.logout(removeProfileData);
    }

    // Remove profile data from page
    function removeProfileData(){
        document.getElementById('profileData').remove();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you find any solution for linkedin login? I have implement it in angular 9. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Getting Started with the JavaScript SDK of Linkedin?

Url: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk#

Comment: LinkedIn javaScript SDK has currently deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Passport along with Node Js to login using Linkedin? It will be, much easier to implement so as well.

Link: http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-linkedin-oauth2/

Comment: Please avoid rhetoric questions in answer. They risk being misunderstood as being not an answer.